# Float.parse calling Float.parse_unsign?

Tags: elixir

I am processing some data, and right now I am trying to calculate the mean of n lists. These lists are inside another list. Here is a sample of the data:

```
[["-0.080025", "-0.080025", "-0.080015", "-0.079178", "-0.066629", "-0.029453",
  "-0.0064417", "-0.019739", "-0.021123", "-0.025398", "-0.055983", "-0.075814",
  "-0.079795", "-0.080022", "-0.080025", "-0.080025", "-0.080025", "-0.080025",
  "-0.080018", "-0.079423", "-0.069868", "-0.032261", "0.017806", "0.035879",
  "0.041343", "0.029148", "-0.026684", "-0.068951", "-0.079376", "-0.080017",
  "-0.080025", "-0.080025", "-0.080025", "-0.080025", "-0.080023", "-0.079873",
  "-0.076878", "-0.056673", "-0.0030618", "0.053119", "0.069893", "0.045678",
  "-0.023749", "-0.06928", "-0.079415", "-0.080018", "-0.080025", "-0.080025",
  "-0.080025", ...],
 ["-0.084085", "-0.084083", "-0.084047", "-0.083717", "-0.080876", "-0.060307",
  "-0.012167", "0.0077519", "-0.02192", "-0.057804", "-0.077836", "-0.083459",
  "-0.084056", "-0.084085", "-0.084085", "-0.084085", "-0.084078", "-0.083947",
  "-0.082947", "-0.078388", "-0.065892", "-0.029419", "0.03784", "0.064259",
  "0.044593", "-0.0024933", "-0.053087", "-0.0779", "-0.083477", "-0.084059",
  "-0.084085", "-0.084085", "-0.083913", "-0.081747", "-0.071199", "-0.046784",
  "-0.016896", "0.016849", "0.063589", "0.081406", "0.07693", "0.050708",
  "-0.0032174", "-0.054017", "-0.078116", "-0.083582", "-0.084068", "-0.084085",
  ...],
 ["-0.083784", "-0.083784", "-0.083764", "-0.083115", "-0.075532", "-0.045746",
  "0.0025923", "0.034508", "0.032723", "0.00070663", "-0.042077", "-0.073005",
  "-0.082723", "-0.083744", "-0.083783", "-0.083784", "-0.083784", "-0.083782",
  "-0.083592", "-0.079842", "-0.055294", "0.0029941", "0.054748", "0.070303",
  "0.057656", "0.041449", "0.01174", "-0.045245", "-0.077217", "-0.08339",
  "-0.083777", "-0.083784", "-0.083784", "-0.083771", "-0.082942", "-0.070474",
  "-0.022136", "0.04515", "0.073387", "0.054989", "0.010515", "0.0099996",
  "0.032238", "-0.0068253", "-0.062245", "-0.081717", "-0.083711", "-0.083783",
  ...]]
```

As you can see, each inner list is really big (256 elements), but they are all formed by small numbers. The idea is then to sum all these lists together with a Enum.reduce, and after divide the resulting list with its size, thus giving me the mean list of all the lists.

Since each number is wrapped inside a string, I have to convert them to float. I found that Float.parse does the job.

Here is the code that does that:

```
def calculate_mean(class_data) do
  size = Enum.count(class_data)

  class_data
  |> Enum.reduce(fn list1, list2 ->
    sum_lists(list1, list2)
  end)
  |> Enum.map(fn e -> e/size end)
  end

def sum_lists(list1, list2) do
  List.flatten(list1)
  |> Enum.zip(List.flatten(list2))
  |> Enum.map fn {e1, e2} ->
    {p1, _} = Float.parse(e1)
    {p2, _} = Float.parse(e2)
    p1 + p2
  end
end
```

Where class_data is in the form of the example shown above.

Here is what I get when I change only the arguments:

```
iex(7)> Naive.Learning.calculate_mean([["-3", "-0.001", "0.301"], ["0.03124", "0.91230", "-0.2938"]])
[-1.48438, 0.45565, 0.003599999999999992]
```

Now with the class_data shown above:

```
iex(9)> Naive.Learning.calculate_mean(class_data)                                                    
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Float.parse_unsign/1
    (elixir) lib/float.ex:41: Float.parse_unsign(-0.16410999999999998)
     (naive) lib/naive/learning.ex:72: anonymous fn/1 in Naive.Learning.sum_lists/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:977: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1261: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:977: Enum.map/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1261: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
     (naive) lib/naive/learning.ex:61: Naive.Learning.calculate_mean/1
```

From what I understand about this error message, elixir is trying to call Float.parse_unsign on a negative number, thus resulting an error. But this is really strange, since I never called that function. Also both lists in both examples had negative numbers, but only one crashed.

Comment: It would be great if you could find the exact string that fails. You can use something like this: `class_data |> List.flatten |> Enum.each(fn (x) -> IO.inspect(x); Float.parse(x) end)` - the last value printed out will be the one causing the failure.

Comment: sadly it does not fail, it prints everything and at the end returns :ok

Comment: You could also just add `IO.inspect({e1, e2})` before `Float.parse(e1)`

Comment: thanks, I found that this is the problem:
{"-0.083784", -0.16410999999999998}, there is a string which is not a string

Comment: I think I get it, the sum_lists expects lists of strings, but the accumulator from reduce has a list of floats.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was with my logic. I was calling a function inside a reduce, where the function expected two lists of strings, and returned a list of floats. 
So now the accumulator of the reduce would pass a list of floats to the function, which you give me the error. 
The problem is solved by adding a pattern matching inside the anonymous function, checking if is receiving strings or floats.

```
def sum_lists(list1, list2) do
  List.flatten(list1)
  |> Enum.zip(List.flatten(list2))
  |> Enum.map fn
    {e1, e2} when (is_binary(e1) and is_binary(e2)) ->
      {f1, _} = Float.parse(e1)
      {f2, _} = Float.parse(e2)
      f1 + f2
    {e1, e2} when (is_binary(e1) and is_float(e2)) ->
      {f1, _} = Float.parse(e1)
      f1 + e2
  end
end
```